# Start lpksetup.exe with Python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, exe

I try to start lpksetup.exe with Python.
I tried:

```
subprocess.call(["lpksetup.exe"], cwd="C:\\Windows\\System32\\")
```

```
os.startfile('C:\\Windows\\System32\\lpksetup.exe')`
```

But I always get this error:

> **[WinError 2] The system can not find the specified file**

The path ist correct (100% sure). When I search the file in the explorer it is there (not hidden or so) but when I print all files in the directory via Python the file isn't there anymore:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Windows\\System32\\"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
```

How can I execute **lpksetup.exe**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy the file into another place. Then it worked. (Out of System32)

Answer (score 1):

As `lpksetup.exe` seems to be an executable file I think the command `os.system`.

Regarding finding the file:

I'm not sure, as I don't use Python on Windows, but it *may* be that you need to replace the (escaped) backslashes with normal slashes like:

```
import os
os.system('C:/Windows/System32/lpksetup.exe')
```

Comment: No os.system ist to execute shell.scripts and for Python you need 2 backslashes or one if you have a r' in ront of the path.